# How to add custom separators in horizontal menu navigation (flex ul) using WordPress Site Editor?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP's Site Editor ( wp-admin/site-editor.php ) to customise the footer for my site.

The footer contains a horizontal navigation menu (ul) that I would like to modify by adding custom separators between each of the elements (li).

Both the ul and the li have `display: flex` which is making it difficult to find a CSS solution that works.

The old way to do this might be to use `wp_nav_menu()`, but what is the new Site Editor way to add custom separator in between the li elements?